# How to include a class from outside API folder in Next.js API WebPack (Cannot access 'class' before initialization)

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js

I have this as my handler in a next API

```
import {ContentfulContentFactory} from "~/controllers/concrete/ContentfulContentFactory";

...
   
export default function handler(
        req: NextApiRequest,
        res: NextApiResponse<Data>,
    ): void {
    

    const query:QueryData = req.query as QueryData;
    const { environment } = query;

    try {
        const testClass:IContentFactory = new ContentfulContentFactory(environment);
        testClass.getHomePageContent();
        res.status(200).json({ environment: environment ?? "NO ENV SENT"});
    }
    catch (e:any)
    {
        res.status(500).json({ environment: environment ?? "ERROR", message:e.message});
    }
    
    
    
}
```

But when I run it locally I get this error:

```
error - Error [ReferenceError]: Cannot access 'ContentfulContentFactory' before initialization
```

On the line where I am initializing it. After some confusion I realised that if I moved ContentfulContentFactory into the same folder as the API, then it worked.

But I don't actually want my file with the API. I want to keep it in the controllers folder (OR at the very least in a place where other actual page files can call it). How do I tell next to include this file when it compiles and webpacks the API?